# Convert object to array of objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I would like to convert an object of the following format :

```
{ From: {"A","B","C"}, To: {"A1","B1","C1"}, value: {1,2,3} }
```

I wanted to convert this array:

```
[
  {from: "A" ,to: "A1" , value: 1  },
  {from: "B" ,to: "B1" , value: 2},
  {from: "C"   ,to: "C1"   , value: 3  }
]
```

How I can convert it in javascript code ?

Comment: The "JSON" array example is not valid JSON

Comment: Step one: `JSON.parse()`, with step two being probably "discover that's not JSON and fixing that", and then step three being converting the parsed object, which is now just plain JS, into whatever format you actually need, using whatever combination of `.map()` and `.reduce` you can come up with.

Comment: Please read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input you have given is wrong because it contains array with `key:value` pairs and object without `key:value`. It should be

```
{ From: ["A","B","C"], To:["A1","B1","C1"], value: [1,2,3] }
```

Now to convert to desired result you can use `map()`

```js
let obj = { From: ["A","B","C"], To:["A1","B1","C1"], value: [1,2,3] }

let res = obj.From.map((form,i) => {
  let value = obj.value[i];
  let to = obj.To[i];
  return {form,to,value}
})
console.log(res)
```